# How to create separate columns for values in Database

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, multiple-columns

I have an SQL query that displays information from different tables in a database. One of the fields is called PieceType and this contains values like PLT, CASE, CTN etc. Each company could have a different number of PieceTypes e.g. company 4 could have just PLT, but company 5 could have 10 different types. I want to display these types in separate columns like:

```
Plt | CASE | CTN
```

My SQL query:

```
SELECT  c.Name,
        jp.PieceType
FROM customer c
LEFT JOIN job_new jn ON ja.JobID = jn.ID
LEFT JOIN job_pieces jp ON ja.JobID = jp.ID
WHERE c.Company_ID = compid
GROUP BY c.ID
```

Right now the query just displays one value from PieceTypes even though the company might have multiple piece types. I tried  `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT jp.PieceType)` but that displays all the values in the same column. I need each piece to be in a separate column.
Sample Database can be found on sqlfiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c34306/3

Comment: I don't really understand why you want different columns, you can instead use case statements for each of the type you have assuming you have limited set .   select c.name, case when jp.PieceType='Plt' then 'Plt' end as Plt, case when jp.PieceType='CASE' then 'CASE' end as 'CASE' from ...

Comment: @BhargavSarvepalli It will help displaying the report I need if they are separate because using one column wasn't displaying them right. I can't create a case for each piece, like I said one company could only have one but another could have 30

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Is there a way to just split the values? Like I said if I use `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT jp.PieceType)` the values appear as CTN,FP,CASE. Would it be possible to split each value into a separate column?

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is a select where you do a lookup of the property you want.

ie:

```
Select 
name,
(select property from job_pieces where companyid = id and property = 'A') as A,
(select property from job_pieces where companyid = id and property = 'B') as B,
(select property from job_pieces where companyid = id and property = 'C') as C
 from company
```

Comment: But would property need to be each piece type? A company could have 30 piece types so I couldn't to a select for each one

Comment: If you have 30 different types in total, you'd have to do 30 loopups.

Comment: You can probably do it rather quickly with search and replace with some copy + past magic

Comment: Do you really need them in different columns at this layer? A more standard way to do it would be to get all the properties and the loop through them at the presentation layer.

Comment: Yes it would be easier to get them in separate columns because the code to display the report is already done. I was just hoping to edit this query

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for PIVOT TABLE. Hope this works :

```
SET group_concat_max_len=4294967294;
SET @COLUMNS = NULL;

/* Build columns to pivot */

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
        DISTINCT CONCAT(
            'CASE WHEN jp.PieceType = "', 
            jp.PieceType ,
            '" THEN 1 ELSE NULL END AS ',
            jp.PieceType
        )
) INTO @COLUMNS
FROM job_pieces jp;

/* Build full query */
SET @SQL = CONCAT(
        'SELECT  
                c.Name,
                ',@COLUMNS,'
        FROM customer c
        LEFT JOIN job_new jn ON ja.JobID = jn.ID
        LEFT JOIN job_pieces jp ON ja.JobID = jp.ID
        WHERE c.Company_ID = compid
        GROUP BY c.ID'
);

/* Prepare and execute the query*/
PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: I get an SQL error for the PREPARE statement. Is that really needed?

Comment: Sorry forgot `INTO @COLUMNS` in the query. Hope this works now. What do you mean by "Is that really needed ?"

Comment: I'm getting the error: Result consisted of more than one row

Comment: Forgot `GROUP_CONCAT` before `DISTINCT CONTAT` . Hope this is the good try :) Sorry for those mistakes it's hard to see a missing element without running the query live.

Comment: ok thanks that got rid of the error but the result it displays is 'PRL', '9', NULL, NULL, '0', '0', '2684.18', '1', 'CTN,FP', 'GROUP_CONCAT(IF(jp.PieceType = \"CTN\", 1, NULL)) AS CTN,GROUP_CONCAT(IF(jp.PieceType = \"FP\", 1, NULL)) AS FP'

Comment: I want it to just display the PieceType. It is getting the PieceTypes, you can see CTN and FP which is correct but it is not displaying them in separate columns

Comment: I've changed the CONCAT part with a CASE WHEN, if it did not work, maybe could you consider making a [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) with fake data so that I can try on this ;)

Comment: Adding the CASE WHEN causes this error: 1 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 1260 Row 16 was cut by GROUP_CONCAT(). I will look into sqlfiddle, I have never used it before

Comment: There was an open parenthesis with no closing one. Now should be better I think.

Comment: After looking at the error, I presume it comes from the fact the group_concat has a greater length than what it's allowed to. So I added the line `SET group_concat_max_len=4294967294;` to prevent it. Let's pray it was the problem !

Comment: that fixed the error but the result is displaying a line of code like before. Will the database I created in sqlfiddle help?

Comment: Yeah it will help because if people use the link (edit your question so that everyone sees it) then people can run their query on it, so I can test and see the bugs much more quickly.

Comment: any luck figuring it out?

Comment: Working on it. The thing is that I thought you had several rows with different jp.PieceType, but you have one row with comma-separated PieceTypes and I'm having trouble with this. When I figure that out I give you my answer.

Comment: sorry I didn't explain everything well. I appreciate the help thank you

Comment: I don't think Pivot table is the correct solution for what I am trying to do. This question is like what I need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5829543/how-to-parse-a-string-and-create-several-columns-from-it. But I don't know how to edit it for my query