# How to delete part of value from column in Teradata SQL?

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have Table in Teradata SQL like below:

```
col1
-------
1234 Odp Berlin
5643 Odp Warsaw
9984 Odp Madrid
```

And I would like to delete "Odp " from "col1" and based on it create "col2", so as a result I need something like below:

```
col1            | col2
---------------------
1234 Odp Berlin | 1234 Berlin
5643 Odp Warsaw | 5643 Warsaw
9984 Odp Madrid | 9984 Madrid
```

How can I do that in Teradata SQL ?

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5829543/how-to-parse-a-string-and-create-several-columns-from-it

Comment: could you reproduce this solution to my question ? And be aware that my question is about Teradata SQL not about MS SQl :)

Comment: I'm not a big TD guy but to my understanding, you should be able to modify the information in the linked answer to work with TD.

Comment: Have you tried to use use the string with an empty string? Something like this

SELECT Col1, oreplace(col1,'Odp ','') AS col2 FROM table_name